# Filter a combo box based on another combobox?

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, filter

I am creating an access 2010 database with information about aircraft type information.

I have 4 Combo Boxes;

```
Aircraft Make
Aircraft Model
Aircraft Variant
Aircraft Feature
```

I would like to filter the model combo box based on the selection in Manufacturer box, then variant combo box based on selection in the model combo box etc etc....

The code below is what I have currently entered for the 'Aircraft Model' Filtered list...

```
SELECT tbl_AircraftModel.[Aircraft Model], tbl_AircraftModel.lku_ShortCode

FROM tbl_AircraftModel

WHERE tbl_AircraftModel.lku_ShortCode = tbl_Aircraft.[Make]'
```

However this just asks me to Enter a parameter value?

Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: `tbl_Aircraft` is not included in the `FROM` clause, so Access is puzzled by `tbl_Aircraft.[Make]` in the `WHERE` clause.  Shouldn't that reference the value selected in one of your other combo boxes (perhaps `Aircraft Manufacturer`)?

Comment: 'tbl_Aircraft.[Make]' is the combobox from which the aircraft model combobox should filter its options?

Comment: So `tbl_Aircraft.[Make]` is the name of a combo box?

Comment: yeh, that field uses a combo box with data from `tbl_AircraftMake`

Comment: With the form in design view, right-click that combo box and select Properties from the dropdown list.  Then on the property sheet, choose the "Other" tab and tell us what text appears immediately to the right of "Name".

Comment: I am new to this whole programming jargon, I think I have my terminology in a muddle..I do not have combo boxes, I have fields in tables, using the lookup wizard, so there is no "Other" tab?

Comment: So you're not dealing with a form at all.  Maybe you're doing something in table design using lookup fields.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: thats correct yeah, `tbl_Aircraft.[Make]` looks up `tbl_AircraftMake`, then `tbl_Aircraft.[model]` looks up `tbl_AircraftModel`, then I am trying to make it so that when the user enters for example Boeing in th `make` field they can only select from 737,747 etc in the `model` field

Comment: OK, I'm unsure whether lookup fields support the type of query you want ... I thought they were only capable of simpler lookups.  But actually I avoid using lookup fields, so I'll have to bail on this.  Maybe someone else can help.  You should edit the question to clarify your situation.

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying to help me, and sorry for the jargon mix up :)

Answer (score 1):

What you wish to do is a routine task in MS Access forms.

Create a form based on your table.  On the form, place some unbound combo boxes. When you want the user selection in Combo Box A to alter the choices displayed in Combo Box B, make the AfterUpdate event of Box A call the Requery method on Box B.